# Scanning the resources of a hierarchy of cloudformation stacks

Tags: aws-cloudformation, boto3

I am frustrated in my attempts to recursively sweep over a hierarchy
of AWS CloudFormation stacks.   I need to take a look at all their
resources.

Recall that one CloudFormation stack can contain yet another stack.

It appears that the description of these sub-stacks returned by
`describe_stack_resources` isn't useful.

An example of my problem follows:

Using Boto3 we can see this stack has has eight sub-stacks:

```
In [22]: resources = cfn.describe_stack_resources(StackName=my_stack_name)['StackResources']

In [23]: len(resources)
Out[23]: 8

In [24]: [r['ResourceType'] for r in resources]
Out[24]: 
['AWS::CloudFormation::Stack',
 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack',
 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack',
 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack',
 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack',
 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack',
 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack',
 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack']
```

Curiously, all these substacks are reported as having the name of the
parent that created them, though they have distinct `PhysicalResourceId`s.

```
In [25]: [r['StackName'] == my_stack_name for r in resources]
Out[25]: [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]

In [29]: resources[0]['PhysicalResourceId'] == resources[1]['PhysicalResourceId']
Out[29]: False
```

If I ask for the resources of the substack using their physical ID it doesn't work, I instead get the resources of the parent:

```
In [32]: p_id_0 = resources[0]['PhysicalResourceId']

In [33]: child_resources = cfn.describe_stack_resources(PhysicalResourceId=p_id_0)['StackResources']

In [34]: child_resources == resources
Out[34]: True
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This command will list the resources of all nested stacks:

```
map(lambda x: cfn.describe_stack_resources(StackName=x['PhysicalResourceId'])['StackResources'], cfn.describe_stack_resources(StackName=my_stack_name)['StackResources'])
```

Refer to the [`DescribeStackResources`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStackResources.html) API documentation for details on request parameters/response elements for this API.

In the request, the `StackName` parameter accepts *either* the stack's name *or* its unique stack ID. In the inner-stack call, you can provide the `PhysicalResourceId`s of the [`AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) resources, because the physical ID (the string returned by the [`Ref`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) intrinsic function) is [defined](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#d0e43649) as the Stack ID for this resource type.

Note that in the response, the [`StackResources.StackName`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_StackResource.html) property represents the name associated with the *parent* stack, not the stack name of the resource being described.

Also note that calling `DescribeStackResources` with the `PhysicalResourceId` parameter returns all of the resources of the *parent stack* containing that physical resource ID, not the resources of a stack *represented by* that physical resource ID, as described in the API documentation:

> Returns AWS resource descriptions for running and deleted stacks. If `StackName` is specified, all the associated resources that are part of the stack are returned. If `PhysicalResourceId` is specified, the associated resources of the stack that the resource belongs to are returned.

Comment: Ok, that works; thanks!   But two things.   I find it quite curious that your passing an id to a parameter that take a name.  First, you write StackName=x['PhysicalResourceId'].    Second, while it's nice that they document what seems like bizzare behavior that asking for the children of X returns the children o the parent of X.   Is my confusion approprate or is there some reason why I shouldn't be confused by that.

Comment: I hacked up an alternate fix, i.e. plucking the stack's name out of the PhysicalResourceID.   stack_physical_resource_id.split(':')[5].split('/')[1]

Comment: I don't think the pluck routine is necessary- for an [`AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) Resource, the `PhysicalResourceID` (what is [returned](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#d0e43649) by the [`Ref`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) intrinsic function in a template) _is_ the Stack ID, and for `DescribeStackResources` `StackName`, you can provide either the stack's name or its stack ID.

Comment: And yes it is all quite a bit confusing, the behavior of this API is a little counterintuitive. Hope my explanation is as clear as possible, at least.